# LaTeX file compiles on my machines, but not through the arXiv process

Tags: compiling, arxiv

I have been trying to understand the error log given to me by arXiv when trying to process my LaTeX file, but I don't understand what is wrong.

Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/6mxULcmC

The file runs perfectly fine on my machine, but it does not compile through the arXiv processing. I have included the necessary graphics, but I do use tikzgraphics in the file to generate some images. I have included all the macro definitions I use in the preamble of the file.

Should I upload my work somewhere else for people here to see it? I don't know where though as the paper is quite long.

also I see this `

```
ikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex)
! I can't find file `tikzlibrarygraphs.standard.code.tex'.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
\catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.45 \usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
```

`

Comment: A friend of mine recently had the same problem, without any graphic file. The reason might be that arXiv uses TeX Live 2011, which is quite old.

Comment: Sorry, OP here. @Bernard does that mean that I am just SOL?

Comment: I don't  know what SOL means.

Comment: Perhaps the best thing to do would be to write to arXiv's webmaster. Many things have changed since 2011 (TikZ, biblatex, &c.).

Comment: it's just an older version of tikz they have, usual workaround is to externalize your tikz images and just include them back as images so no tikz processing is needed at that end

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is...pretty unfortunate since I have a decent amount of images that I now have to export. Why is arXiv using such an outdated system?

Comment: I know nothing about their setup, but if I had an archive of thousands of documents that worked with the setup I had, I'd need a _really_ good reason to apply an update and risk breaking them:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah.. true. I suppose i'm just upset because now I have to do all this extra work. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Just for the record, arXiv is in the process of upgrading to TeX Live 2015: https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes