# Tex file compiles on my laptop but not on arxiv

Tags: arxiv

This is my first time trying to upload something to the arxiv. The file runs on my laptop with no issues. But when I try to upload it to arxiv I get the following error:
http://pastebin.com/k0ZgQGgt

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297227/latex-file-compiles-on-my-machines-but-not-through-the-arxiv-process?rq=1 (they use texlive 2011 which is just too old (especially tikz has changed a lot since then)  that one doesn't have an answer yet though...

Comment: According to that, I need to externalize my tikz diagrams, if I understand correctly. How does this work exactly?